# Nested class with constexpr constructor, legal when deriving from template parameter with non-constexpr constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, constexpr

```
template<typename T>
struct Outer
{   struct Inner : T
    {   constexpr Inner() {}
    }
    m;
};

struct NonConstexpr
{   NonConstexpr() {}
};

int main() { Outer<NonConstexpr> o; }
```

With Visual C++ (2015 and 2017), this results in `error C3615: constexpr function 'Outer<NonConstexpr>::Inner::Inner' cannot result in a constant expression`

Both G++ and Clang accept the code. Is this a bug in the Microsoft compiler?

Compiler explorer:
https://godbolt.org/g/SfZfMh

**Edit:**
To clarify, it works if we make Inner a template. But it gets a bit ugly.

```
template<typename T>
struct Outer
{   template<typename T_>
    struct Inner : T_
    {   constexpr Inner() {}
    };
    Inner<T> m;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

[dcl.constexpr]/4:

> The definition of a constexpr constructor shall satisfy the following requirements: ... either its *function-body* shall be `= delete`, or it shall satisfy the following requirements ... for a non-delegating constructor, every constructor selected to initialize non-static data members and
>   base class subobjects shall be a constexpr constructor.

Since `NonConstexpr::NonConstExpr()` isn't `constexpr`, the derived class constructor `Outer<NonConstexpr>::Inner::Inner()` which calls it can't be `constexpr` either.

Comment: Is it a bug in GCC and Clang?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I think so

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I thought the Inner constructor counted as a member of a template. In which case different rules apply, it would be enough that some instantiation could satisfy the requirements for constexpr.